# Force binding update when doing something on a non-focusable control

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a problem which I've solved in a non-elegant way, and was wondering if there's any better solution.

I have a View which may have textboxes that only update their binding when losing focus (their bound properties use `UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus`). This is "almost" correct... I could set the binding's `UpdateSourceTrigger` to `PropertyChanged` and I wouldn't have a problem and everything would work as expected... however, there is some potentially computationally expensive stuff happening on the updating of those bound properties (involving deep checkings on the edited object which could potentially get long) so I actually only want to update the binding after I'm done with the editing.

This is posing problem with toolbars, since their buttons are not focusable, so clicking on them (and issuing the command) doesn't actually make the textbox lose focus so when the command is executed, the binding hasn't updated (think of a entity editing view, with a toolbar 'Save' button, that when clicked calls a save command which actually saves the entity. In this case, the entity would be saved with the value of the textbox before it lost the focus)

I could check the bindings before raising the command and update the source (this is what I'm doing now), however that means, either:

- Having access to the bindings (or the controls) where the command is executing. This is discarded for the complete unelegance of the solution. The command action is defined on some other library which should be WPF-agnostic.
- Executing the command on a code-behind event handler and perform the binding update (or just set the focus to something else and let WPF update the source) before raising the command. This is what I'm doing now and it's what I don't like (I'd prefer assigning the command directly to the toolbar button if there's other solution).
- Have the View interface have a "ForceEndEdit()" which the View executes and call it whenever I'm performing some operation which might pose this problem. I find this rather odd and would prefer not to do it.

Is there any way to tell WPF to update the bindings *"whenever the user calls a command -or clicks a button- outside the control not necessarily losing focus"*? In case there's not, is there any solution any of you have found to this problem that is more elegant than the proposed above and I might have not thought of?

As I said, triggering the binding update `OnPropertyChanged` (which is what I've seen proposed to similar -though not identical- questions) is not a good enough solution in this particular case.

**PS**: this would not be only for textboxes, but any kind of editing control (datepickers, range pickers, etc.) and those controls might be third-party and I wouldn't necessarily have access to their source code.

**PS2**: I'm using .NET 4.5

Comment: What version of .NET are you using?

Comment: 4.5, sorry, will add to the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are doing something computationally expensive during `OnPropertyChanged()` with `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` you should consider using `Delay` in the `Binding` so that the `Binding` updates only once the user has stopped entering a value in the control.

This could solve your problem because it's interaction time-based rather than relying on some other event/occurance before initiating the update. This property is new in .NET 4.5 which is why I asked what version of .NET you were using.

Comment: That would work in some cases (actually most of them, but not all),  `Delay` only delays updating the Source, not the Target... this would require some big changes in the project since many of my views are automatically generated and the "usual" binding source and target are swapped (the editing control is the target, not the source). I see how this might be weird, but when doing it (out of my ignorance, I reckon) I assumed that since it was TwoWay that wouldn't matter.

I'll think about the implications of changing it and get back to you (I wonder however why Delay only works on the Source).

Comment: Btw, I'm upvoting since that'd be the "correct elegant" solution on a normally defined view... if I get to actually change how the views are generated and make the bindings "correctly", I'll mark it as answer. Meanwhile, I'll listen to other potential solutions :-)

Comment: "the editing control is the target, not the source"... Um. This is the normal way around? `ViewModel` is the Source (of the data), with the editing control as the Target (of the data), so do you mean you have the editing control as the Source? O_o

Comment: Err, yes, sorry, I meant the opposite... and I understand how this is not correct and sounds weird, but as I said, it looked ok to me when I did it since "TwoWay is TwoWay" (first decently-sized WPF project and lots of ignorance I'm paying now :-) ).

Comment: Before I start making tests on this solution, I have another question: does the delay ocurr immediately after doing something else than propertychanging? I mean... say I put a delay of 500ms and the 'save' button has a ctrl+s shortcut. If I'm editing the text and press ctrl+s before those 500ms, would the binding update before issuing the command? If not, then I'm in the same situation (the idea is: all bindings should have been updated before raising the command, no matter what caused the command to raise)

Comment: You also need to be realistic here, I think. 500ms is 0.5 seconds. How quickly do you think a user is **reasonably** going to try hit that Save button or Ctrl+S shortcut after finishing typing? I think even with a 500ms delay, you're unlikely to have dirty Binding updates. If the Delay was 3000ms, then yes, absolutely, but not with 500ms. FYI in a live application I worked on our update delay was 300ms for reference. ;-)

Comment: I typically press ctrl+s on visual studio at the same speed I'm typing my code :-) . As a slow typer as I am, I'd reasonably say I can easily do around 3-4 characters per second if I don't have to think when typing them (and I definitely don't think when pressing ctrl-s). Anyway, I'll take your word for it on the 300ms and do some measurements with average users, then delay a bit less to be on the safe-side.

Having had a look at the codebase, the implications to change all those "not correct" bindings would not be a lot actually, so this might work as a solution.

Comment: I just made some quick tests on the actual application (not a boilerplated view) and even with the mouse having to click on a ribbon bar I'm able (without much effort) to click the save button under 200ms. I'm afraid this solution won't work for me without doing extra checking. In this particular app, I can't afford a "fast user" losing data because of this. Particulary I have a "Save and close" button on the window that would not allow the user to see the actual data has not been saved until it's too late (that wouldn't be a problem with just "save" as it'd warn before closing later) :-/

Comment: I'd say you need to do two things then:
  1) Move the computationally heavy stuff onto a background thread
  2) Disable Save until the heavy computation is complete.

Comment: Well, it's "computationally heavy enough" so that it'd make your typing "not smooth", but acceptable for a focus changing, if you know what I mean. I precisely don't want the saving to happen till that's complete, but if I set `CanExecute` on the command then the button becomes disabled (and that's not what I want).

I guess a decent solution would be to use a "proxy-command" which updates the bindings on the focused control then calls the real "save" command. Much like using an event-handler but a bit more elegant (and I can bind the command to the other command if needed)

Comment: I see it this way: You can't allow the user to save until the binding is updated and fully validated. Use the validation process to disable the button until it's fully validated. It's better to have a deterministic "you can save now" than chance a dirty save due to not updating the binding. If you tell the user what you're doing (have a status bar saying "Validating..." while the process is running, then "Validation complete..." when it's done), the user experience will be good because the user is informed of what you're doing. Disable the button as soon as a control's property is edited.

Comment: As I said, the computation is long enough to make typing not smooth, but not enough long to "really interrupt"... I'd probably have the button blinking while I'm editing, which is not what I want. The process that makes sense is: "finish updating bindings when clicking the save button, then save", which is what I'm doing now... I wished there was a binding trigger to do it other than "actively losing focus" or "having to wait some time"... like: "on click on any other non-focusable control", but since there is not, the event handler I'm using now, or a better "bindable-proxy-command" will do.

Comment: I'll mark your answer as correct, since both your answer and your comments are spot-on, although they don't apply in my very specific case. As a side note, I've fixed all the incorrect bindings, and it was not that much work :-)